# ¿Por qué no carga la imagen en el servidor http (python)?

Tags: python, bash, servidor, http, curl

Tengo el siguiente servidor http hecho en Python:

```
import os

#funcion que retorna el content type de un archivo
def get_content_type(path):
    ct = b"Content-Type: "
    if path.endswith(".html"):
        return ct + b"text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"
    elif path.endswith(".css"):
        return ct + b"text/css\r\n"
    elif path.endswith(".js"):
        return ct + b"text/javascript\r\n"
    elif path.endswith(".jpg"):
        return ct + b"image/jpg\r\n"
    elif path.endswith(".png"):
        return ct + b"image/png\r\n"
    elif path.endswith(".gif"):
        return ct + b"image/gif\r\n"
    elif path.endswith(".ico"):
        return ct + b"image/x-icon\r\n"
    elif path.endswith(".txt"):
        return ct + b"text/plain\r\n"
    else:
        #content type por defecto con utf-8
        return ct + b"text/plain\r\n"

#funcion que retorna el content length de un archivo
def get_content_length(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            path = path + "index.html"
            response = b"Content-Length: " + str(os.path.getsize(path)).encode() + b'\r\n'
            return response
        else:
            response = b"Content-Length: " + str(os.path.getsize(path)).encode() + b'\r\n'
            return response
    else:
        return b"Content-Length: Not Found"

#funcion que maneja el mensaje de regreso
def return_message(code, num):
    response_header = code
    path = "codes/" + num + ".html"
    if os.path.exists(path):
        file = open(path, "rb")
        response_data = file.read()
        file.close()
        datatype = get_content_type(path)
        datalength = get_content_length(path)
        response_header += datatype + datalength
        return response_header + b"\r\n" + response_data
    else:
        datatype = b"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
        response_data=b"Error Content Not Found"
        datalength = b"Content-Length: " + str(len(response_data)).encode() + b"\r\n" + b"\r\n"
        response_header += datatype + datalength
        return response_header + response_data

def handle_request(request):
    print("Request: ", request)
    request_lines = request.split("\n")
    request_line = request_lines[0].strip()  # Eliminar espacios en blanco alrededor de la línea de solicitud
    method, path, http_version = request_line.split(" ") #Metodo, ruta, version de http
    print(path)
    if not path.startswith("/"):
        # Generar la respuesta 400
        return return_message(b"HTTP/1.1 400 HTTP Bad Request\r\n","400")

    path = path[1:]  # Eliminar el primer caracter "/"
# try:
    #418
    if method == "BREW":
        return return_message(b"HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a teapot\r\n","418")

    #505
    if http_version != "HTTP/1.1":
        return return_message(b"HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported\r\n","505")
    #405
    if method != "GET":
        return return_message(b"HTTP/1.1 405 HTTP Method Not Allowed\r\n","405")

    #main del servidor
    if path == "":
        path = "index.html"

    #probar si es un directorio
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        if not path.endswith("/"):
            path = path + "/"
            path = path + "index.html"
            if os.path.exists(path):
            # Abrir el archivo solicitado
                file = open(path, "rb")
                response_data = file.read()
                file.close()
                # Generar la respuesta 301
                response_header = b"HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\nLocation: /" + path.encode() + b"\n"+ b"\n"
                datalength = get_content_length(path)
                datatype = get_content_type(path)
                response_header += datalength + datatype
                response = response_header
                return response + response_data
        
        #probar si existe
        # 200 directorio + index.html
        if os.path.exists(path):
            # Abrir el archivo solicitado
            path = path + "index.html"
            file = open(path, "rb")
            response_data = file.read()
            file.close()
            # Generar la respuesta
            response_header = b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            datalength = get_content_length(path)
            datatype = get_content_type(path)
            response_header += datalength + datatype
            response = response_header + b"\r\n" + b"\r\n" + response_data
            return response

    #200 archivo
    # Inside the if condition for checking image extensions
    # if path.endswith((".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".ico")):
    #     if os.path.exists(path):
    #         # Open the image file
    #         file = open(path, "rb")
    #         response_data = file.read()
    #         file.close()
    #         # Generate the response
    #         response_header = b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
    #         datalength = get_content_length(path)
    #         datatype = get_content_type(path)
    #         response = response_header + datatype + datalength + b"\r\n\r\n" + response_data
    #         return response

    if os.path.exists(path):
        # Abrir el archivo solicitado
        file = open(path, "rb")
        response_data = file.read()
        file.close()
        # Generar la respuesta
        response_header = b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
        datalength = get_content_length(path)
        datatype = get_content_type(path)
        response_header += datalength + datatype 
        response = response_header + b"\r\n" + b"\r\n" + response_data
        return response
    

    else:
        #probar si el archivo existe
        if os.path.exists(path):
            # Abrir el archivo solicitado
            file = open(path + "index.html", "rb")
            response_data = file.read()
            file.close()
            # Generar la respuesta
            response_header = b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            datalength = get_content_length(path)
            datatype = get_content_type(path)
            response_header += datalength  + datatype
            response = response_header + b"\r\n" + b"\r\n" + response_data
            return response
        else:
            # Generar la respuesta 404
            return return_message(b"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n","404")
    # except:
    #     return return_message(b"HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\n","500")



def run_server():
    host = 'localhost'  # Dirección IP local
    port = 2131  # Puerto para escuchar las solicitudes

    # Crear un socket TCP/IP
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Asociar el socket a una dirección IP y puerto
    while True:
        try:
            server_socket.bind((host, port))
            break
        except OSError:
            print(f"El puerto {port} está en uso. Intentando con el siguiente puerto.")
            port += 1

    # Escuchar las conexiones entrantes
    server_socket.listen(1)
    print(f"Servidor escuchando en http://{host}:{port}")

    while True:
        # Esperar una conexión entrante
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"Conexión entrante desde {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")

        # Recibir los datos de la solicitud
        request_data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        print("Solicitud recibida:")
        print(request_data)

        # Generar la respuesta
        response_data = handle_request(request_data)

        # Enviar la respuesta al cliente
        client_socket.sendall(response_data)

        # Cerrar la conexión
        client_socket.close()

run_server()
```

Cuando hay una imagen en el html (como en el ejemplo siguiente), sólo me muestra el texto alternativo, a pesar de que es capaz de recuperar la imagen (no da error 404) y con cUrl me deja hacer la solicitud bien.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
  <p>The requested page could not be found.</p>
  <img src="codes/img/404.png" alt="404 Error Image" width="300">
</body>
</html>
```

En ese ejemplo, donde debería ir la imagen sólo sale el texto alternativo "404 Error Image"

¿Cual puede ser el error?

Esta es la cabecera cuando tira error 404:

```
TP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 242

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
  <p>The requested page could not be found.</p>
  <img src="codes/img/404.png" alt="404 Error Image" width="300">
</body>
</html>
```

Y esto sale si hago curl http://localhost:2131/codes/img/404.png -i
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No comiences la ruta de la imagen con `codes/`, ya que es relativa a dónde ocurra el error. Inicia la ruta con `/codes/`, así, sin importar dónde ocurra el error siempre tendrá la ruta correcta. Es muy probable que no la está mostrando porque la propia imagen da un error 404 debido a que se referencia en una ruta incorrecta.